# Open file dialog defaults to showing hidden files

Tags: gnome, hidden-files

My *open file dialog* is defaulting to showing hidden files, I have to press Ctrl-H to get to the files I want, but this is not saved across instances of the dialog.

I can't find a settings panel to change this behaviour, including Nautilus preferences, nor a key in the configuration editor. Is there a way to have the open file dialog default to not show hidden files?

Answer (score 25):

## GTK 2

Edit the file

```
~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini
```

There is a line

```
ShowHidden=true
```

change to

```
ShowHidden=false
```

Save and close.

## GTK 3

Run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden false
```

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem and this fixed it for me because changing settings in Nautilus file browser doesn't affect File Open/Save dialog window

Comment: This did not work for me in Mozilla Firefox. This is what helps: right-click in the folder view of a dialog box and uncheck "Show Hidden Files".

Comment: For GTK 3, run this: `gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden false`

Comment: @AlexanderPozdneev you should post that as an answer so I can upvote.  That was the only solution that worked for me!

Comment: @LordElrond, thanks for the hint. I edited the answer. Once it is approved, that will be OK to delete my comment.

Answer (score 14):

You may have checked showing hidden files in preferences. In Nautilus (file browser) click **Edit>Preferences** and in **Views** tab if **Show hidden files and backup files** is ticked, remove the tick.

[image: Hidden Files Setting]

Comment: That was the first place I looked. **Show hidden files and backup files** is and has been unchecked.

Comment: +1 to Erich Youngren's comment. This answer pertains to Nautilus file manager, not the file selector dialogue.

Answer (score 5):

To fix this in 13.04, I had to right click on the dialog and uncheck "Show Hidden Files"

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.10 you have to click on the **gear button** on the right of the toolbar and the click on **Preferences** -> **View** and remove the tick on **Show hidden and backup files**.