# How can I reset Terminology settings if the terminal is inaccesable?

Tags: configuration

I’m on Ubuntu 12.04 running GTK 2.x+
I was experimenting with new terminals and messed up [terminology](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/terminology), I tried to do `sudo apt-get autoremove terminology` thinking that would remove the program and settings,  then reinstalled it `sudo apt-get install terminology` but when I run the program I get the same issues and this output if run via another console.

```
renamon@Gibson{~}:terminology
ERR<13620>:elementary elm_prefs.c:2139 _elm_prefs_init() prefs iface module could not be loaded, the prefs widget won't function
ERR<13620>:efreet_cache lib/efreet/efreet_cache.c:1108 on_send_register() org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown The name org.enlightenment.Efreet was not provided by any .service files
renamon@Gibson{~}:
```

Any help on this issue? How do I reset terminology prefrences? Can this application even be used in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you run any other terminals? I would guess that removing `terminology`'s config files will solve this. What's the output of `echo .terminolog* ./config/terminology*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, application-specific settings are kept either in hidden dotfiles/dotdirectories in your `$HOME` or in subdirectories of `$HOME/.config`. For example, the config file for `conky` is `~/.conkyrc` while the configuration files for the `links2` browser are in `~/.links2/` while those for `vlc` are in `~/.config/vlc`.

So, have a look at the hidden files in your `$HOME`, look for any whose name contains `terminology`. You can do this with this command:

```
echo .terminolog* ./config/terminology*
```

That should list the config files/dirs of `terminology` and deleting them (or moving them) should get the program back.

---

Remember that even if you have removed the default terminal, you can still run `xterm` or  always drop to a cirtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (get back to your GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALt</kbd>+ <kbd>F7</kbd>, or F8 depending on your system).

Alternatively, you can list the files in the file browser if you enable ["show hidden files"](https://askubuntu.com/a/109576/85695).

Answer (score 2):

1. `sudo apt-get remove --purge terminology`
2. `sudo apt autoremove`
3. `find $HOME -name "*erminology*"`

   Now you know that config files are here (or?)

   ```
   /home/dx/.config/terminology
   ```
4. `rm -r ~/.config/terminology`
5. `sudo apt-get install terminology`
6. Profit!

PS.:

This answer is based on [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829322/terminology-works-only-in-guest-session).