# terminology works only in guest session

Tags: 16.04, terminology

The program Terminology works perfectly only in guest session.
Normal user or root experience following error:

```
ERR<9467>:terminology main.c:3001 elm_main() Could not initialize key bindings. ERR<9467>:efreet_cache lib/efreet/efreet_cache.c:1108 on_send_register() org.enlightenment.DBus.Canceled Canceled by user. CRI: lib/eet/eet_lib.c:626 eet_shutdown() eina_log_print() unknown domain -1, original message format 'Init count not greater than 0 in shutdown.'
```

**syslog:**

```
failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/terminology.desktop file: cannot process file of type application/x-desktop

As-WARNING **: failed to rescan: Failed to parse /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index file: cannot process file of type text/plain

Gs-WARNING **: failed to get updates: no results to show
```

`find $HOME -name "*terminology*"`
 - shows empty config folder

`terminology.desktop` file looks for me ok: http://pasteall.org/81724

All non-guest users cannot open terminology as well.

The problem persists after purging and reinstalling emulator.

Searching for the answer I stumble upon the guest user session: why unity  is able to use an application library in such a different way from unity in regular user session ? To make it understandable, maybe leads to further solution? Does it make sense for you? What is the background of these issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Does it work if you create a new, non-guest user? If this is the case, you have leftover configuration files in your home directory.

Comment: Could you paste the contents of the `terminology.desktop` file mentioned in the log?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant information. Also, the output of `find $HOME -name "*erminology*"` will probably help. :)

Comment: «there is no other relevant information as that what I already wrote about» You keep linking a pastebin-like website instead of adding the information to your question. Comments could be deleted at any time and the question would be left without those pieces.

Comment: @user43484  Below your question there is a button "Edit". Click that and add all the information you posted into comments into the question. This is going to be much more useful than leaving everything in the comments

Answer (score 0):

This terminology has some problem with transparency settings and breaks. I didn't find the solution so need to run it without transparency (what a shame).Terminology is hard coded so each modification hast to be made directly in the  source code and then compiled again. This issue is not appearing in 14.04.